# How can I tell when the current process is done with an IO operation, specifically chart.SaveImage?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, io, data-visualization

In my console app, I create a chart using the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart class. I am able to create the chart from my data and save the image using this call:

```
chart.SaveImage(chartImagePath, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Most of the tutorials online cover the saving of the image, which I have accomplished. The problem arises when I try to use this image that was just created. I want to save it to an attachments list, so I call this function:

```
internal static Attachment GetAttachment(string chartImagePath, string contentName)
{
    var attachment = new Attachment(chartImagePath);
    attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
    attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
    attachment.ContentId = contentName;
    attachment.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
    attachment.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(chartImagePath);
    return attachment;
}
```

The call to this function fails with an IOException: The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process.

I have tried a couple of things: (1) checking for File.Exists(chartImagePath) before proceeding, but this doesn't help because the file does exist right after creation, but the process hasn't released it yet (2) using a retry pattern to swallow exceptions, 3 retries wasn't enough.

I cannot find any documentation on when chart.SaveImage completes or if there is a function I can invoke asynchronously after that call completes. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: `when chart.SaveImage completes` It is synchronous. It completes when the method stops executing. Have you tried disabling your antivirus?

Comment: Thank you. It was a filename collision bug, I was writing to the same filename ‍♂️

Comment: This is why a [mcve] is critical @Freakishly. ;)

Answer (score 0):

That error simply means some process is still running on or with the file. It will make sense to call dispose on the chart object after saving.

```
 var chart=new Chart(); // creating and plotting chart.
 chart.SaveImage("image.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
 chart.Dispose();      // Release all resources that has to do with the image.
```

When I performed a simple operation with the saved image using the code below, everything worked just fine.

```
var stream = File.Open("image.png",FileMode.Open);
Console.WriteLine(stream.Length); // Output: 1068.
```

Comment: Did it work even if you commented out the `Dispose`?

Comment: Yes it will work. It wasn't the Dispose that was tripping me up, it was writing to the same filename. I will post a better question with clearer code next time.